# PrintOperation force unix dialog?

Tags: gtk, pygtk

Is it possible to force GTK to use unix print dialog instead of platform native one?

Comment: it is obviously system-dependent.

Comment: @Louis Since the documentation states "UnixPrintDialog is used when there is no platform-specific native dialog", one can at least suspect that it is possible to force the usage of a generic dialog instead of a native one.

Comment: I do not see that in the docs. What I see is quite different : the use of the NATIVE gtk print dialog, that is called "gtkunixprint.PrintUnixDialog" but the "unix" word in its name has not a lot to see with unix.

Comment: http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkprintoperation.html quote:On platforms which do not provide a native print dialog, GTK+ uses its own, see gtkunixprint.PrintUnixDialog

Comment: yes : "ITS OWN".  Not the unix one, despite its name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The Unix print dialog only works on Unix.